# Auto-follow Facebook friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a user follow their FB friends in my app automatically. I am able to get ids of user's FB friends, but I don't know how to go about auto-following.

I get their friends' uid(fb id), so I think I would need to find users in my app whose uid matches uid of the user's fb friends list and then make a user follow those automatically. How would you do that?

user.rb

```
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
       end
  end

#gets uid of user's fb friends

   def fbfriends
     @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
        begin
          @fbfriends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends", fields: "id")
          @uids = @fbfriends.map{ |v| v.values }.flatten
        rescue Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError => e
          redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
        end
          @friends = User.where(uid: @uids)
    end

  def fb_user_id
    self.fbfriends.map{ |v| v.id }
  end

   after_create :follow_fbfriends!

  def follow_fbfriends!
    relationships.create!(followed_id: fb_user_id)
  end
```

user show

```
<%= @user.fb_user_id %>
```

browser output

```
[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible steps:

1. In `@fbfriends`, get those `UID`s of a user's friends.
2. `@friends = User.where(uid: @fbfriends)` will give all those user profiles which exist for any of those UID.
3. Iterate over the `@friends` and set-up relationship b/w that user and the friend for `followers`.

**EDIT**:

As can be seen, `@fbfriends` in your code is returning an array of hashes, and not the UIDs alone. So first, extract the UIDs as:

```
@uids = @fbfriends.map{ |v| v.values }.flatten
#=> ['1654449181']
```

Now, use this new array with `User.where(uid: @uids)` to retrieve the users with those UIDs(if present). For setting up relationship b/w the users, you may want to read the [Michael Hartl's guide chapter](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#cha-following_users).

**EDIT 2**: 
In `follow_friends!`, you must iterate over the friend ids you obtain and create relationship for each one of them as:

```
def follow_fbfriends!
  fb_user_id.each do |friend_id|
    relationships.create!(followed_id: friend_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: 2. I tried that before, but I always get either "#<ActiveRecord::..." or an empty array. Could you please write a code(modify my example) for that?

Comment: You may have to modify `@fbfriends` definition in your code above. Can you edit your question with some code and output? I would like to see whether or not it successfully retrieved the UIDs, or not.

Comment: I updated the post. I can get UID, but now the problem is how to get user ID in my app and then make the User follow his friends in my app.

Comment: Updated the answer. Extract UIDs properly; extract the `users` by passing them to `User.where(uid:..` and set up relationship. I think, it's pretty logical now.

Comment: For setting the relationship, you may want to read - http://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#cha-following_users

Comment: I edited the post. Also, here's an error I get when trying to register the first user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643096/validation-failed-followed-cant-be-blank