# Validation failed: Followed can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to implement auto-following for every user on my site who has friends on FB. When someone in the friend list registers to my site, new user should automatically follow people who are on my site and his/her FB friends list.

When I tried to register the first user on the site, I got an error in the title. How do I get around that? Please check if my code for auto-following is good.

I am also using G+ for authentication.

This is what I have now in user.rb:

```
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

   after_create :follow_fbfriends!

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
        user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.image = auth.info.image
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
       end
  end

   #gets uid of user's fb friends

   def fbfriends
     @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
        begin
          @fbfriends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends", fields: "id")
          @uids = @fbfriends.map{ |v| v.values }.flatten
        rescue Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError => e
          redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
        end
          @friends = User.where(uid: @uids)
    end

  #User ID on my site(based on UID)
  def fb_user_id
    self.fbfriends.map{ |v| v.id }
  end

  #This should automatically follow user's fb friends if any of them are on my site
  def follow_fbfriends!
    relationships.create!(followed_id: fb_user_id)
  end
```

relationship.rb

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
#  validates :follower_id, presence: true
#  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Please do paste the error log. Just saying that I got error in this doesn't do justice with beneficial traces.

Comment: The error means you've got validation somewhere. I can't see it in your `user` model - do you have it in `relationship` model or similar?

Comment: I updated the post with relationship model. I commented out 2 lines - now I don't get an error, but the auto-follow doesn't work as well(user doesn't follow his FB friends on my site). Is the code good?